# Want to display X amount of lines evenly separated on the screen

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display a number of horizontal lines on the screen.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

I attempted the following though the screen height returned seems to be bigger than the actual screen height so the divisions end up off the screen. I end up with the image shown at https://imgur.com/a/Dx1wH1Y.jpg

```
      final int _numLines = widget._verticalLines;
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _numLines,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / (_numLines + 1),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            );
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is like this.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int _numLines = widget._verticalLines;
    return Column(
      children: getChildren(_numLines),
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getChildren(int number) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      list.add(
        Container(
          height: 1.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly,try this if it is not let me know

```
   ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
          shrinkWrap:true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height:120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.red,width: 2,)),
            ),
           
          );
        },
      )
```

Comment: That's roughly what I'm doing currently. Though I'm trying to separate each line evenly depending on the screen height. So setting the height to a hard coded number is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaQuery` and divide the height of the screen by the given number

Example: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5`.  - This will be dividing the screen into five equal parts, this will work across all devices.

**Code:**

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap:true,
          itemCount: number,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / number,
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            );
          })
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing. For some reason the division calculation ends up wrong and I end up with lines that are misaligned.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it should work and I've been trying all sorts of variations and still kept on being misaligned. I haven't tried out different phones/screens. I'm guessing that the screen resolution/size might have something to do with it.